# Sorting criteria for the view of votes

Tags: feature-request, voting, sorting, favorites-tab

The favorites tab can [be sorted by activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/213963/michaelt?tab=favorites&sort=activity&StartDate=2014-08-20%2003:38:51Z).  This sorts based on the last activity date for the entire question (I don't see exactly what field that is on Data.SE - might be a 'fun' join to get that from the question favorited to the max modification date all the posts that have it as a parent).

The request: add a similar sort order ability for the votes.

Currently, all votes are sorted by when they are cast and only by when they are cast.  That's it.  However, I am fairly certain that there's a join done against the Posts table anyways (to get the post title).

The use case for this is I want to see the posts that I've down voted and what their last activity date was, sorted.  This would allow me to look at things that I've voted on in the past and either remove the down vote (the issue was improved) or possibly vote to delete it if issues on the answer haven't been addressed.

The thing is, I can't do it currently.  And the list is [*far* too long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzz1H.png) for me to do manually.  And so, if I could see what *has* changed recently, there's a chance that I would go back and review the changes.

People oft complain about the lack of visibility in getting attention on improved posts.  Sometimes people suggest some sort of personal review queue (if this was put in /review, you'd likely get even *fewer* people going there)... or notifications (consider for a moment the implications of an edit triggering half a dozen notifications and how many edits are done - or the hundreds ).

This allows people who are interested in activity on posts they have voted for to see it without spamming the system or the user with things that most people are going to ignore anyways.

Comment: for what field, probably the last timestamp of anything related to that question